# Структура базы данных firebase vue

Tags: vue.js, firebase, vuex

подскажите, как организовать структуру базы данных.

1. Есть пользователи
2. Каждый пользователь может создавать свои записи
3. У каждого пользователя есть история записей и избранные записи
4. Каждый пользователь может опубликовать свою запись в "глобал", чтобы другие пользователи увидели ее.

Куда лучше складывать записи ?
Сейчас складываю в /users/${uid}/records/
В /public сейчас сохраняется ownerId и recordId

Как быть при получении публичных данных ?
Не вариант же делать "кучу" запросов в цикле - this.$store.dispatch('fetchPublic', {ownerId, recordId) ?

Как получить все записи, удовлетворяющие ownerId и recordId ?

Comment: Хранить все записи в коллекции records с ссылкой на владельца и флагом публичная или нет.

Comment: @ValeraKvip Подскажите, пожалуйста, если я в таблице каждого пользователя буду хранить id записей, которые ему принадлежат. В отдельной таблице "записи", будут находиться записи всех пользователей. Как отфильтровать и получить данные для конкретного пользователя. 
Пытаюсь отфильтровать данные таким способом - firebase.database().ref(`records/info`).orderByChild("recordOwnerId").equalTo(uid).getRef(). Но выходит не то, что мне нужно.

Comment: я использую firestore, а не realtime database, в любом случае я не смог бы ответить потому что не знаю структуру бд и что не так с конкретным выражением. Думаю можно задать отдельный вопрос где подробно сформулировать суть проблемы.